# How can I get Chrome to recognize schema changes immediately?

Tags: cme

When I make a CMS Schema change using Google Chrome (SDL Tridion 2011 SP1) - components using this schema do not show the change - even if I empty the cache, or do a hard reload (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). I thought that this might be server side caching, so restarted all sorts of stuff on the CM box - to no joy. Then I noticed that in Firefox the changes are visible immediately, so I guess it is a chrome thing. Any ideas? Its very annoying - currently to update components I have to open a new incognito window, or use Firefox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a Windows PC, pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> usually works for me (say OK to leaving the page if the question is asked), not sure what the difference with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is.

Comment: Just F5 doesnt empty anything from the cache, so have no idea why that would work for you and not for me. Ctrl F5 is the same as Ctrl+Shift+R (see http://www.zeigen.com/shortcuts/2008/06/25/force-reload/)

Comment: F5 works for me too with Chrome (just F5, nothing else)

Comment: Hmm. that works for me too - weirdness - not sure why the other options dont work, but as long as I have one method!

Answer (score 4):

As you've said clearing the cache doesn't work, I'm not sure whether this will help, but there are a couple of cache-clearing buttons [available as extensions for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/cache).

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you're talking about PC Chrome here, but as F5 on an Apple keyboard is used to the dim the keyboard light you have to jump through a couple of steps:

1. Launch "System Preferences"
2. Click the "Keyboard & Mouse" icon
3. Select "Keyboard Shortcuts" tab
4. Hit the little "+" button under the main white area
5. In the little pup-up window select "Google Chrome" as the Application
6. Type in "Reload This Page" in the "Menu Title" field exactly as it appears in the Chrome's View menu (no quotes of course)
7. Click inside the "Keyboard Shortcut" field and hit F5 key (or any desired combination)
8. Restart Chrome to make it work

Hope this helps :)

Comment: On a mac fn+F5 would also do the trick. ;)

Comment: doesn't here, i had to resort to the method described

Answer (score 2):

`cmd` + `shift` + `r` is part of it since that's a hard refresh.

Also be sure to close out all your other Tridion-related tabs. I've found that more than one tab opened to the same instance of Tridion can prevent a hard refresh from working.

The other thing that can help is to right-click inside of the Tridion GUI and click refresh.

If all else fails and you can't wait the 15 seconds or however long it might take, just pull up Tridion in incognito mode: `cmd` + `shift` + `n`

Answer (score 2):

Not very sure about SDL Tridion 2001 SP1, but I can assure you that in SDL Tridion 2011, this is not a browser thing but a cache thing. There are multiple caches which may be causing this behaviour. Starting from soft to hard solution, you can try below steps one by one:

1. Press F5 or Press Ctrl + F5  - If does not work go to step 2 - *This does not work at least for me even for a single time while I am accessing the CME over the internet though my PC*
2. Close the Browser and Reload the CME  - If does not work go to step 4
3. Go to CMS Server and Restart SDL Tridion Content Manager App Pool -  - If does not work go to step 5
4. Go to DCOM+ configuration and restart SDL Tridion Content Manager DCOM+ application

Also, in the installation folders there is a config (I need to search for its complete path), in which you can set this cache behaviour and set expiration timeout for the cache. Say if you set this to 0, the performance may be slow but such changes will be immediately visible.

**UPDATE**

The cache duration is specified in
`%TRIDION_HOME%\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration\System.config`.

The default is: `<cache httpexpireduration="P10Y0M0DT0H0M0S"/>`

The format is documented on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations, but in general "pushing" the non-zero to the right will make the cache expire sooner.

Comment: In my experience with the issue that Will has described, a hard-refresh in a single tab is 98% effective. I've only had to try incognito mode a handful of times, and once have I ever logged onto the server. I feel like the solution you're offering is an extreme edge-case that probably is resolving a much different issue than a simple component not reflecting the latest schema updates.

Comment: May be it is working for many people...but I can definitely challenge the 98% as I have seen it not working for almost every time I made change in a schema...and the only solution was either restarting dcom+ our waiting for around 20 minutes and then pressingf5